# Using VS2017 can I compile the DB structure and data into an SQL file, then upload it into another DB?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Using VS2017. Can I compile the DB structure and data into an SQL file, then upload it into another DB?

I'm thinking the SQL file will have the Create Table Statements and all that. Then later in that same file the statements to build the data.

Comment: Take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362002(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Within T-Sql or using external tools? If it's the former then, no, not easily. If it's outside then you've a better shot.

Comment: Microsoft tools have limited support for that... They generally can't work out dependencies properly (i.e. table x is dependent on table y and needs to be created before table y) You're better off using a third party tool, like Red Gate's SQL Compare...

Comment: I took a leap of faith and make a straight text file. 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ( [CustomerID] INT PRIMARY KEY, [CustomerName] NVARCHAR (40) NOT NULL, [YTDOrders] INT NOT NULL, [YTDSales] INT NOT NULL );
Called it whatever.slq and it looks like it worked. Problem is how can i auto generate that from VS2017.

Comment: I found the syntax that worked. I was not dropping tables correctly. So i can execute more then 1 command now. Any idea how to grab your existing DB from VB2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took each table individually then each table data script, put them in a file and uploaded it. Took a bit of time but it worked.

basically it was :

```
CREATE DATABASE TMSProgram;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Billing] (
    [ordernumber]  INT             NOT NULL,
    [billto]       NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
...
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Billing] ([ordernumber], [billto], [totalcharges], [tcposted], [paid], [driverpay], [dpposted], [paperwork], [compid]) VALUES (2, N'ABC Fruits', CAST(50.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)), N'y', N'y', CAST(15.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)), N'y', N'none', 20045)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Billing] ([ordernumber], [billto], [totalcharges], [tcposted], [paid], [driverpay], [dpposted], [paperwork], [compid]) VALUES (3, N'Steveggg', CAST(36.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)), N'y', N'y', CAST(40.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)), N'y', N'none', 20045)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Billing] ([ordernumber], [billto], [totalcharges], [tcposted], [paid], [driverpay], [dpposted], [paperwork], [compid]) VALUES (4, N'Dan''s Tackle Shop', NULL, N'y', N'y', NULL, N'y', N'none', 20045)
...
```